# "npm start" is causing error - ENOENT: no such file or directory ... package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

I tried to create a React app using NPX. Everything went well, but when I run `npm start`, I get the following error:

```
$ npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Administrateur.TEST\Desktop\reactProjects\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Administrateur.TEST\Desktop\reactProjects\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrateur.TEST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-19T22_43_34_181Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you inside the project directory?

Answer (score 11):

while running npm start make sure that your terminal opened in which directory where package.json is present

Answer (score 2):

Ciao, you have to launch `npm init` before `npm start` to create your missing `package.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

`npx create-react-app my-app` will create a directory called `my-app` (which contains the app).

To use the app, you'll need to navigate to the new directory: `cd my-app`.

Once inside the directory, you can run `npm start` to start the app.